# I never live on land - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You'll often find me in a book

You can catch me if you can hook

And smoke me red.

If you follow me, you will be a lost boy.

I like to tinker with your attention, ahoy

I never live on land.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> A (red) herring

You'll often find me in a book

> You can find misleading red herrings in mystery books, they may also be in a fish encyclopedia!

You can catch me if you can hook

> Can be fished with a hook and line

And smoke me red.

> Can be cooked by smoking, making the flesh red

If you follow me, you will be a lost boy.

> A red herring will lead one away from the answer

I like to tinker with your attention, ahoy

> Carrying on from above

I never live on land.

> Herrings live in the water

Comment: This is the correct answer, very quick! If you could just add a justification for the first line and I'll accept. I promise its not difficult to figure out

Answer (score 36):

You are

> Peter Pan

You'll often find me in a book

> Peter Pan was a book

You can catch me if you can hook

> Captain hook tries to catch Peter

And smoke me red.

> Smoking the pipe with the "red man"

If you follow me, you will be a lost boy.

> The Lost Boys follow Peter

I like to tinker with your attention, ahoy

> An allusion to Tinkerbell, and Peter's taunting nature

I never live on land.

> Neverland is Peter's home land.

Comment: Pretty sure this is right.. flies above my answer!

Comment: That is logical reasoning, but it was the misleading answer :)

Comment: Arg, I've been deceived!

Comment: @hypern Love it! Said fish caught me like a fish!

Comment: @Matt, think he was referring to my answer.. :(

Comment: Surely not. My answer *is* your answer, in a manner of speaking ... haha. Yours is correct, @Arth

Comment: Haha, I secretly prefer yours... Love the idea of a red herring actually being a red herring and the explanations have a lovely cryptic feel to them!

Comment: This works so much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: My mind has just been blown. The red herring was a red herring.

Comment: @Mirror318 Sadly it wasn't, it was the answer... I'd happily give up the 15 rep for a good ol' mind melt though :)

Comment: Both answers are red herrings! my brain ...